# Supervisord: Do not kill processes from crond

Tags: supervisord

Supervisord kills/reaps cron jobs. Its crond from BusyBox in Alpine

```
2019-08-05 11:31:00,816 INFO reaped unknown pid 384
```

Process is visible as with ps as `[scraper]` -> scraper is my bash script

Crontab looks like this:

```
*/5 * * * * export DM_TIMEOUT=20 && /opt/scripts/scraper >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This is my supervisord config.

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
user=root

[program:darkhttpd]
command=darkhttpd /opt/scraper/ --port 7000 --default-mimetype text/plain
user=root
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:scraper]
command=crond -f
user=root
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

I would like to: A) **do not kill cron job**  B) **kill cron job if takes more than X seconds**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a misunderstanding here.

`supervisord` is not killing anything. My understanding is that when a program ends, `supervisord` prints that reap message as part of it's cleanup.

It should also give that programs exit status. Status(0) means it exited correctly, and there's not much else to worry about.

If it is a numbered status, then there may be a problem with your script that you need to investigate, but it's not anything to do with supervisord at that point!